# Assigning SQL value retrieved of dept to Session["UserAuthentication"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm retrieving the value of dept with following SQL query wirrten in C# from the table ts_dept - how would I assign it to `Session["UserAuthentication"]` when `(CurrentName != null)`?

```
   protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Login_Box.UserName;
        string pwd = Login_Box.Password;

        string strConn;
        strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["team13ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        Conn.Open();

        string sqlUserName;
        sqlUserName = "SELECT dept FROM ts_dept WHERE id=@username AND pass=@pwd";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, Conn);
        com.Parameters.Add("@username", username);
        com.Parameters.Add("@pwd", pwd);

        string CurrentName;
        CurrentName = (string)com.ExecuteScalar();

        if (CurrentName != null)
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
            Session.Timeout = 1;
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always use [_parameterized queries_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kinds of codes are open for [_SQL Injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You want to assign what to what?

Comment: I've updated my code to include parametrised queries :-). Well what I want to do is assign the value of dept (there can only be one) that the SQL query `SELECT dept FROM ts_dept WHERE id=@username AND pass=@pwd` gets to `Session["UserAuthentication"]` when `(CurrentName != null)` i.e. a match is found

Comment: You want to do `Session["UserAuthentication"] = CurrentName;` ?

Comment: NEVER use Session for authentication purposes.  Session is cleared out whenever the worker process recycles, and is not load balancing friendly.  It's also not secure, as session cookies are easily hijacked.  Use the built in FormsAuthentication cookie system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going from memory here (not at my C# machine), but try this:

```
object CurrentName = com.ExecuteScalar();
if (CurrentName != null && CurrentName != System.DBNull.Value) {
    {
        Session["UserAuthentication"] = (string)CurrentName;
        Session.Timeout = 1;
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
    }
}
```

If I recall correctly, CurrentName will be null if the query returns no results, or System.DBNull.Value if the query returns a result but ts_dept.dept is null.

Also take heed of the comment about using Session for authentication - if you're in a load-balanced cluster it just plain won't work. Start switching this to Forms authentication.